# Which distributors are authorized to sell device units?

Tags: purchasing

Which distributors and partners are officially authorized to sell Raspberry Pi's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/) and [RS Components](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/) are the only companies listed on [RaspberryPi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) authorized to sell the official devices so far.

Additionally, their is an official [Wiki page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Buying_Links_By_Country) of additional sources that the RPi can be purchased from, outside the UK. (Thanks [@Shane Hudson](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9/8) for this information!)

Comment: Yes, but right now you need to wait in line :-)  They ar out of stock, and new Pis are being produced... But it takes time. It's important to register your interest (see Lee Davis' answer) so you will be able to buy yours when the new units arrive.

Answer (score 5):

You need to register your interest before you can purchase:

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi

http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/bespoke/bespoke7.jsp?ICID=I-RASP-HPBLOF-0015&bespokepage=farnell/en_UK/promotions/raspberryPi.jsp

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out, the **only** two distributors are Farnell and RS Components, however they go under other names in different countries. For a complete list see the [public wiki page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Buying_Links_By_Country).

Answer (score 3):

There are three places you can buy Raspberry-Pi from.

1. [Element 14](http://www.element14.com/community/groups/raspberry-pi)
2. [RS Components](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi)
3. [Allied Electronics (Owned by RS Components)](http://www.alliedelec.com/RaspberryPi/)

Comment: Allied Electronics is owned and run by RS Components.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deadly keen to get hold of one, then they are available on eBay:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=raspberry+pi

However, you are likely to pay over the list price.

Comment: The question asks specifically about authorized distributors.

Comment: Well, to be fair, when I answered, the title was "How can I acquire Raspberry Pi?"...

Answer (score 1):

I registered with the RS Components form to express interest.  It needs your name and email.  I did this on March 3.

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi

They sent me an authorization code and an individual link on May 22 that I used to order.